# Select all adjacent elements without copying the numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bunch of points with format `point = [time, latitude, longitude]`.

So, I have got myself a numpy array that looks something like -

```
points = numpy.array([
    [t_0, lat_0, lon_0],
    [t_1, lat_1, lon_1],
    [t_2, lat_2, lon_2],
    ...
    [t_n, lat_n, lon_n],
])
```

Now, I need to do something that gives me next and previous points to each of these points like:

```
next_points = numpy.array([
    [t_1, lat_1, lon_1],
    [t_2, lat_2, lon_2],
    ...
    [t_n, lat_n, lon_n],
    [nan,   nan,   nan],   # Note how `nan` is put where next does not exist
])

prev_points = numpy.array([
    [nan,   nan,   nan],
    [t_0, lat_0, lon_0],
    [t_1, lat_1, lon_1],
    [t_2, lat_2, lon_2],
    ...
])
```

So, that I can apply my distance function -

```
next_distances = distance_function(points, next_points)
prev_distances = distance_function(points, prev_points)
```

Now, this task appears in a function that gets called in a loop around 1000 times,

It would nice if I could get `next_points` and `prev_points` without creating a copy of `points`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It looks like you're computing the same distances twice, assuming your distance function is commutative, that is `dist(a, b) == dist(b, a)`.

Comment: yes, but it does not matter because `distance_function`, only calculates distance for unique pairs that are not already in the cache, and caches the distances for later... so that should not be an issue....

Comment: If you're iterating the points arrays inside the distance function you can use `itertools.chain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just about shifting the array:

If you `nan`-pad the `points` array on both sides, you can do

```
next_points = points[1:]
prev_points = points[:-1]

d_next = distance_function(next_points, points[:-1])
d_prev = distance_function(points[1:], prev_points)
```

Although if this is a true distance function, then you only need to do either `d_next` or `d_prev` and shift again accordingly.